# Many-to-one relationship to implement tags: How to count how many times a tag is used?

Tags: mysql

I'm experimenting with a tagging system which is a many-to-one relationship. My schema is:

**items** table:

- item_id
- comment

**comment _ tags**:

- item_id
- tag_id

**tags** table:

- tag_id
- tag_name

I've been reading of implementation designs at the links at the bottom but got stuck. I can insert tags without a problem.

How do I fetch every tag that has been used **and** get how many times it has been applied to an item in the **comment _ tags** table?

http://www.pui.ch/phred/archives/2005/04/tags-database-schemas.html

[SQL Query for Product-Tag relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388687/sql-query-for-product-tag-relationship)

Comment: I'm a little confused over your terminology and the naming of your tables - would comment_tags in fact be better named items_tags? 

Also, I think you're representing a many-to-many relationship - each tag belong to many items, and each item can have many tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t.tag_name, COUNT(*)
FROM tags AS t
    INNER JOIN comment_tags AS c_t ON c_t.tag_id = t.tag_id
GROUP BY c_t.tag_id
ORDER BY t.tag_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

not the correct names, but mostly correct syntex

```
select TagName, count(TagName)
from TagTable
group by TagName
```